# Use a variable (containing hex) to convert to binary type

Tags: php, binary, hex

So the setup I'm using is a variable contains a Hex code, example `5` for the binary `1001` (example) - And I have tried to convert it to the binary using the method:

```
$Bin = "\x5"; # Would = Binary: 1001
```

But I wanted to try to use a variable instead of the `5`, like:

```
$Hex = '5';
$Bin = "\x$Hex";
```

I also tried:

```
$Hex = '5';
$Bin = "\x{$Hex}";
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what are you doing here? and what exactly you want as outcome?

Comment: something like this:- https://eval.in/667277  . But this is surly not hex "\x5".

Comment: From what I understand and was answered in an older question, `$bytes = "\x42";  // 0100 0010` is how you would make the Binary data type, and I'm making a Binary Compression device so this is needed with variables. Sorry if confusing :-)

Comment: May be you want like this:-https://eval.in/667291

Comment: btw hex 5 is not bin 1001. it is bin 101. bin 1001 is hex 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just as simple as,

```
$hex = 0x5;
```

here is a [demo](https://eval.in/667301)

```
<?php
$value = unpack('H*', 0x5);
echo base_convert($value[1], 16, 2);
```